# Getting "SWTException: Widget is disposed" when trying to remove drag and drop listeners

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, drag-and-drop, swt

I have created a custom view in Eclipse which implements a part listener.

```
public class CodeBuilderView extends ViewPart implements IPartListener
```

I am adding drag and drop support for the view. In order to remove the drag and drop listeners, I have overridden the dispose() method as below.

```
@Override
public void dispose()
{
    getSite().getPage().removePartListener(this);

    if(viewDragSource!=null && viewDragSourceAdapter!=null)
        viewDragSource.removeDragListener(viewDragSourceAdapter);
    if(viewDropTarget!=null && viewDropTargetAdapter!=null)
        viewDropTarget.removeDropListener(viewDropTargetAdapter);

    super.dispose();
}
```

However I am getting an SWT Exception on the line "viewDragSource.removeDragListener(viewDragSourceAdapter);". I thought it was necessary to dispose of the listeners before disposing the view, and that is exactly what I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Stacktrace below:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.removeListener(Widget.java:962)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.removeDragListener(DragSource.java:685)
at codebuilder.views.CodeBuilderView.dispose(CodeBuilderView.java:472)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:224)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:373)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.uninject(InjectorImpl.java:180)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.uninject(Requestor.java:158)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:82)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:107)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.removeListenersTo(EclipseContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.uninject(ContextInjectionFactory.java:144)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.disposeWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:118)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:933)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:887)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.hardClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1924)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1547)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$15(WorkbenchWindow.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$10.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1579)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1576)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$14.run(Workbench.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$21(Workbench.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$19.run(Workbench.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1380)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1543)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$15(WorkbenchWindow.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$10.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1579)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1576)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1590)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:520)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer$11.shellClosed(WBWRenderer.java:564)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:98)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Decorations.java:308)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Decorations.java:1696)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4612)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDragSource` has already been disposed by SWT so you can't do any more operations on it. Since it is disposed the listeners lists have already been cleared.

You can test for this with:

```
if (viewDragSource != null && !viewDragSource.isDisposed()) {
    ... viewDragSource is safe to use ....
}
```

Comment: So I don't need to manually drop the listeners? Does eclipse automatically do this job? In that case, can I remove the statements to drop the listeners?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just out of curiosity, how do we determine when we should manually dispose of listeners and when eclipse handles it implicitly?

Comment: Generally SWT Widgets will be disposed automatically when the window they are in is closed (most SWT objects are derived from Widget)